# Tensor product of the fraction field of a domain and a module over the domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> Given a fraction field $k(x)$ of the polynomial ring $k[x]$ over a field $k$ and an integral domain $R$ that is also a $k[x]$-module, is it true that $k(x) \otimes_{k[x]} R \cong Frac(R)$?

I think that it has to do with the simple property of tensor products: $R\otimes_R M \cong M$, for an $R$-module $M$, but I am not sure how to prove it. Is there something more general that this is a corollary of?

Comment: By  $k(x)\underset{k[x]}{\otimes}R$ you are localizing $R$ as $k[x]$ module, i.e. inverting $x$. But by $Frac(R)$ you are localizing $R$ as $R$ module, i.e. you are inverting nonzero elements in $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because you are only inverting the polynomials in $x$. e.g.

$$ k(x) \otimes_{k[x]} k[x,y] \cong k(x)[y]$$

Also,

$$ k(x) \otimes_{k[x]} k[x] / (x) \cong 0 $$

Comment: Could you tell me how do you prove the first one?

Comment: The easiest way is to just write down the isomorphisms: the forward direction is multiplication, and to get the backwards direction, find a common denominator. Alternatively, recognize that $k[x,y]$ is a free $k[x]$ module on the basis $\{ 1, y, y^2, \ldots \}$, and the tensor product should give you the free $k(x)$ module on the same basis. (then check that it's also a ring isomorphism and not merely a $k[x]$ module isomorphism)